# When / How does Tomcat pick the concrete class for the ServletContext interface?

Tags: java, tomcat

So I have this little code:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        System.out.println(servletContext.getClass());
    }
}
```

which prints out:

```
class org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
```

So ServletContext is an Interface, which means the getServletContext() method returns an Interface.. So how does Tomcat know what Concrete class (ApplicationContextFacade in this case) to use? How or when does it decide?

Comment: Never thought about it, but I am pretty sure, that the tomcat will simply create a ServletContect instance while deploying the web-app. The concrete implementation is made within org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade

Comment: +1 for using a `final` local.

Comment: @ErikAllik And I have only types sout and pressed "TAB" which was automatically converted to System.out.println(""); and my cursor was already in between the double-quotes. :) Thanks.

Comment: Why do care about the internal impl of `ServletContext`?

Comment: @Braj Ah, the why do you care question.. :) I just do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat will create on Context instance per webapp so that it can know which request goes to which servlet. And I believe `ApplicationContextFacade` is an implementation of the `ServletContext` which Tomcat uses internally to achieve this. May be understanding how contexts work in Tomcat will help to understand this better. [Check here for starters](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-context)

Comment: Yes, I am guessing that the Implementation of `ServletContext` interface is up to the people who create the Container i.e Tomcat. The same code on another container like jboss might give a different output.